# Neo4J Java Bolt Driver

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am currently using the new SDN 4 ogm.properties file to configure the HttpDriver and was going to test with the new Neo4J 3.0 version.  Has the new Bolt driver been released yet to test with or is there a scheduled release date for it?  Currently the documentation only lists the Http or Embedded options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Bolt driver is work in progress. It'll be released when Neo4j 3.0 is out. We don't have scheduled dates for milestone releases yet.